# Initial conditions to solve an ODE?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the following inhomogenous linear ODE (4th order):

$$q_0\cdot\sigma + q_1\cdot \dot\sigma + q_2\cdot \ddot\sigma + q_3\cdot \dddot\sigma + q_4\cdot\ddddot\sigma = p_0\cdot\epsilon + p_1\cdot\dot\epsilon + p_2\cdot\ddot\epsilon + p_3\cdot\dddot\epsilon + p_4\cdot\ddddot\epsilon$$

This equation describes the creeping ($\epsilon$) behaviour of a material under a given applied stress ($\sigma$). The coefficients $q_n$ and $p_n$ are also time-dependent. The rheological model used is a generalized-maxwell-model.

The applied stress and also the material-parameters are given for each instant in time, like shown in the following picture:

[image: spannungsgeschichte]

Because of the time-dependent parameters $p_n$ and $q_n$, I guess that there exist no analytical solution.

Since a numerical solution without the usage of matlab is costly (in programming as well as in thinking about it), I am looking for an **approximation.**

Therefore, I want to solve the problem in time-steps ($t_{i+1} - t_i$) and assume that:

- because it is a linear problem, the Boltzmann-superposition-principle can be used and is valid
- in one time-step the **parameters $q_n$ and $p_n$ remain constant**
- the **tension** in- or decreases **linear**
- before $t_0$, there was no load applied - there exist **no loading-history**

Now, I think that it is possible, to **solve the equation analytical** (with Laplace-transformation) for each time-step by the usage of correct **initial conditions.**

For the **first time-step** $t_1 = 1 - t_0 = 0$, they are:

- $\sigma(t_0) = 0$
- $\dot\sigma(t_0) = \frac{\sigma(t_1)-\sigma(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}$
- $\ddot\sigma(t_0) = \dddot\sigma(t_0) = 0$
- $\epsilon(t_0) = 0$
- $\dot\epsilon(t_0) = \ddot\epsilon(t_0) = \dddot\epsilon(t_0) =0$

If I use them, I can solve the equation and get a function $\epsilon^\star(t_i) = ...$ which is valid just for the actual time-step.

For the **following time-steps** ($t_{i+1} - t_i > t_0$) I define the following initial conditions:

- $\sigma(t_i) = \sigma(t_i)$
- $\dot\sigma(t_i) = \frac{\sigma(t_{i+1}) - \sigma(t_i)}{t_{i+1}-{t_i}}$
- $\ddot\sigma(t_i) = \dddot\sigma(t_i) = 0$
- $\epsilon(t_i) =$ The value that the function $\epsilon^\star(t_i)$ gives for the end of the time-step $t_{i} - t_{i-1}$, which is the initial condition for the actual time-step.

And for the derivatives' initial conditions, I differentiate the function $\epsilon^\star(t_i)$ to get $\dot\epsilon^\star(t_i)$, $\ddot\epsilon^\star(t_i)$ and $\dddot\epsilon^\star(t_i)$ - now I have the values for the derivatives at the end of the previous time-step, which are the **initial conditions** for the actual time-step.

Thats the way I want to try it.

**So my question:** I know that it might be a "rough" approximation; but is the way mathematically correct? Or are there some mistakes in, which I haven't seen yet?

Thank you in advance!